# Lost Text Destroying Site Loading Time

Tags: wordpress, loading

My wordpress site has been absolutely destroyed by a site loading time of between 40 seconds and one minute.

The website is http://orangeoctop.us/. The site has W3 Total Cache enabled which does not seem to be helping. Wondering if you can diagnose and help fix the problem.

Play hard!

Comment: home page over 7 MB, many images 500+ kB, you really need to make it less heavy.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the way I'd go about it:

1. Fix the Javascript Errors
2. Add custom image sizes and serve the appropriate size
3. Compress Images
4. Move blocking JavaScript to bottom of page, before `</body>`
5. Enable HTTP Keep-Alive

If you follow those steps, you should see a decent speed increase.